# parse - can't send push notifications from device

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform, push, send

Hi I'm trying to send a push notification from a device to another.

Here's my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
            pushQuery.whereEqualTo("gender", "male");

            ParsePush pushMsg = new ParsePush();
            pushMsg.setQuery(pushQuery);
            pushMsg.setMessage("Hey Male!");
            pushMsg.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {

                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(e!=null)
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    else
                        Log.i("Send push", "Success");
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem is when I try to send the notification the log shows "Success" but I receive nothing in my device.
When I put the same parameters on the dashboard it works perfectly.
Please do guide me regarding this issue.

Comment: Is your client push enabled?

Comment: What do you mean enabled? When I send from the dashboard I do receive a notification on my phone. It does not work only when I try to send from the device itself.

Comment: Edit: I also tried to send the push notification through cloud code. I get a 'success' response from the callback and yet I receive no notifications...

Answer (score 0):

Your second device is not registred or not loggined, or you doesn't set to him "gender"= "male" here is
 how to register [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-signup)

how to login [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-login)

how to set "gender"= "male" after logining:

```
ParseUser u= ParseUser.getCurrentUser() ;
        u.put("location", point);
 u.saveInBackground();
```

also set Title to push

```
    ParsePush pushMsg = new ParsePush();
            pushMsg.setQuery(pushQuery);
  pushMsg.settitle("title");
            pushMsg.setMessage("Hey Male!");
pushMsg.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: Both devices are registered and logged-in.
Queries are according to the information iv'e been putting.
And there is no method called 'settitle' in ParsePush.

Comment: Did you "allow send from devices" notifications? in your project on website Parse.com settings?

Comment: Open your project, click on "Settings"- at the left under "General" click on "Push" - in this settings turn on "Client push enabled"